# Como retornar o valor dentro de uma função?

Tags: javascript, jquery, funções

Qual a maneira mais correta de fazer um `return` na resposta de uma function, tenho o seguinte código:

```
$('random-button').click(function(){
    console.log(moveFile());
});

function moveFile(fileID, newFolderID, currentFolder){
     gapi.client.drive.files.update({
        'fileId': fileID,
        'addParents': newFolderID,
        'removeParents' : currentFolder

    }).execute(function(resposta){
        return resposta;
    });
}
```

Preciso enviar de volta o valor obtido como resposta, já tentei salvar toda a função em uma variável porém o `return` vem como `undefined`, como posso fazê-lo?

Comment: Nesse caso aí, me parece que é falta de sincronia. Ao chamar a função no console.log, a função não tem uma resposta pronta, ela ainda vai processar alguma coisa, mas a chamada da função não espera e retorna "undefined".

Comment: Oi Leo! Dá uma olhada às respostas que juntei. Se ainda não conseguires resolver/perceber o problema diz que parte ainda não está clara.

Comment: Obrigado @Sergio a primeira solução funciona bem para mim, apesar de que eu pensasse que existia uma solução mais elegante, já vi esse tipo de uso antes e pensava que fosse gambiarra.

Comment: Em casos desses, assíncronos, ou encadeias dentro da callback ou então usando `async/await`, não há outra maneira de usar `var x = respostaDaCallback;`